# IEEE floating point , how to calculate the bias

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

if we have 10 bits floating point . 4 bits=exponent and 5 bits are the fraction.
how to calculate the bias?

is it 2^4=16-1= 15 ?

is that correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd expect it to be 2<sup>number of bits in exponent - 1</sup> - 1 (or 7 here), as is the case with more common IEEE-754 formats. Check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008).

Answer (score 0):

The 10 bits are being used for mantissa so basically the range of binary number that can appear in mantissa position lies between 000000000000 (10 zeros) and 1111111111 (10 ones) but since the floating point number is signed the maximum mod value of the number can be 111111111 (9 ones)
So the range of mantissa will be -511 to +511

As for the bias, it will be maximum mod value of the mantissa. Thus, here the bias is 511.
By adding 511 to the range of mantissa it is shifted to the range between 0 and 1022.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. In IEEE-754 there's only one bias, the exponent bias. The exponent bits are used to represent a few special cases (denormalized mantissa, infinity and "not a number") and a range of exponents from some minimum value (negative) to some maximum value (positive). This range is encoded with a positive bias (equal to the negative of the minimum exponent value (which is itself negative, hence the positive bias)). It's not 1's or 2's complement or sign-magnitude representation, it's biased. The question says that there are 4 exp bits, not 9 or 10.